# Bash pass string argument to python script

Tags: python, bash, escaping, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a bash script which reads variable from environment and then passes it to the python script like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -n "${my_param}" ]
then
    my_param_str="--my_param ${my_param}"
fi

python -u my_script.py ${my_param_str}
```

Corresponding python script look like this

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My script')
parser.add_argument('--my_param',
                    type=str,
                    default='')

parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
print(parsed_args.description)
```

I want to provide string with dash characters "Some -- string" as an argument, but it doesn't work via bash script, but calling directly through command line works ok.

```
export my_param="Some -- string"
./launch_my_script.sh
```

gives an error `unrecognized arguments: -- string` and
`python my_script.py --my_param "Some -- string"` works well.
I've tried to play with **nargs** and escape `my_param_str="--my_param '${my_param}'"` this way, but both solutions didn't work. 
Any workaround for this case? Or different approach how to handle this?

Comment: `--` marks the end of arguments for a command in the normal case.

Comment: You should **always** double-quote Bash parameter expansions unless you explicitly want Bash to perform word splitting... and you probably _don't_ really want word splitting. :) See the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting) and [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net).

Comment: Look at `sys.argv` to see what `bash` is giving your script.  `argparse` can only parse the strings in that list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your bash needs to look like this:

```
if [ -n "${my_param}" ]
then
    my_param_str="--my_param \"${my_param}\""
fi

echo ${my_param_str}|xargs python -u my_script.py
```

Otherwise, the quotes around the parameter string will not be preserved, and "Some", "--" and "thing" will be passed as three separate arguments.

Comment: Really nice xargs-fu! Works perfectly with python argparse.

Answer (score 2):

For the limited example you can basically get the same behavior just using

```
arg = os.environ.get('my_param', '')
```

where the first argument to `get` is the variable name and the second is the default value used should the var not be in the environment.

Comment: Thanks, but I tied to bash passing case

Answer (score 0):

The quotes you write around the string do not get preserved when you assign a Bash string variable:

```
$ export my_param="Some -- string"
$ echo $my_param
Some -- string
```

You need to place the quotes around the variable again when you use it to create the `my_param_str`:

```
my_param_str="--my_param \"${my_param}\""
```

Comment: That's not right. That would turn `my_param_str` into a single argument of the form `--my_param Some -- string`. The quotes should be around `Some -- string`.

Comment: @Rawing In that case they would have to be written in this line: `my_param_str="--my_param \"${my_param}\""`